# FireFox extension replacing Ads to my own images

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I am looking for FireFox extension that will change Advertisement to my own jpgs. It seems, that AdChange For AdblockPlus 1.0.1 by Thibaud MATHIEU is what I need, but it doesn't work with latest FireFox, more over, it doesn't work with latest AdBlock Plus extension.

Another example is Add-art extension... but it replaces not all Ads that AdBlock blocks.

So, are there any other extensions which will replace Ads to my own pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Add-On at http://www.virtualmiracle.net.   It replaces ads with an image of Jesus.

Comment: This link is broken. Could you provide an official firefox addon link?

Answer (score 0):

Not an extension, but IMHO equally useful: a filtering proxy like [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/). It also [allows for replacing ads by a custom image](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#SET-IMAGE-BLOCKER). Just activate [banner filtering](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#FILTER) by size or by URL and pass your custom replacement image's path to the [`set-image-blocker`](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#SET-IMAGE-BLOCKER) action.